# How to avoid buffer overflow on drupal hidden fields?

Tags: php, security, drupal

I did a test run on a finished website using IBM Appscan and it returned a bunch of errors with a lot to do with the drupal search form block. Here's an extract of one of the errors:

```
    [13 of 37] Parameter Value Overflow
Severity: High
Test Type: Application Invasive
Vulnerable URL: http://[my-web-address]/contact
CVE ID(s): N/A
CWE ID(s): 120
Remediation Tasks: Limit the length of input fields to avoid buffer overflow
Variant 1 of 5 [ID=97491]
The following changes were applied to the original request:
• Set parameter 'form_build_id's value to
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA...
**Request/Response:**
This request/response contains binary content, which is not included in generated
reports.
**Validation In Response:**
N/A
**Reasoning:**
The test caused the server to stop responding (an erroneous response was returned, such as cut
connection or time out). The original request was then resent and also failed, confirming that the
server had stopped responding.
```

Appreciate any pointers on what needs to be done, thanks.

Comment: `substr($_GET['form_build_id'], 0, 100);`

Comment: So this would be included in a custom module? would it be invoked using hook_form_alter()?

Comment: Filtering input is rather trivial task. If it is complicated on drupal (I really don't know how it is) and drupal is so insecure... you're on a wrong way.

Comment: If input filtering was a trivial task, we would not need helper functions like filter_var(). And substr() would be enough even for non-English strings. Sadly, it is not a trivial task and is often done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use language of the form input other than English it is better to use `mb_substr()` function, which preserves strange characters like `é, ù`, etc... (almost like kirilloid solution) and `filter_var()` function, which strip tags and optionally strip or encode special characters in order to protect yourself from different types of injection attacks.

```
$form_build_id = mb_substr(filter_var($_GET['form_build_id'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), 0, 100);
```

Here are the [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) details and here [filter_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) details.
Note that `mb_substr()` requires PHP version 4.0.6 or higher and `filter_var()` function requires PHP version 5.2 or higher.

Comment: Thanks @budiony does this mean I'd use a module that limits such characters on a site-wide scale like so: `mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){ $form['form_build_id'] =  mb_substr(filter_var($_GET['form_build_id'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), 0, 100);
}`

Comment: Yes, indeed, if you plan to use it often like some sort of filtering module for user input it is better to predefine your own protection solution (function or class if you are aware of OOP programming practices), but the easiest (and some time the fastest) way is to create a function.

Comment: As this is a security question, i'm going to point out that php4 and php5.2 are out of support and no longer receive upstream security patches.

Answer (score 0):

The '`form_build_id`' input is an internal identifier from Drupal's Form API. It is used early in [`drupal_build_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7). It should be a base-64 encoded sha-256 hash, with + replaced with -, / with _ and any = padding characters removed.

Form altering functions are likely unable to touch it before the buffer overflow happen. So the right place to sanitize it would be in `drupal_build_form()` with something like

```
  [...]
  $check_cache = isset($form_state['input']['form_id']) && $form_state['input']['form_id'] == $form_id && !empty($form_state['input']['form_build_id']);
  if ($check_cache) {
    $form_build_id = drupal_substr(filter_var($form_state['input']['form_build_id'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), 0, 100); 
    $form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);
  }
  [...]
```

But the best is to [report this as a security issue](https://drupal.org/node/101494) on Drupal.org and submit your patch there. That would be the best place to get your issue and fix reviewed.